# C# Inheritance with dynamic data

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have classes B, C, D... X that all inherit from class A.

The only difference in them is that they all have single POD property, let's call it Data. They all have different Data structs, but otherwise they are completely the same.

For example:

```
class A  {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    //etc. common variables
}

class B : A {
   public DataForB Data {get; set}
}

class C : A {
   public DataForC Data {get; set}
}
```

You get the idea.

So for each type A to X I can cast the Data to an object like this.

```
var b = new B();
object dataB = (object) b.Data;

var c = new C();
object dataC = (object) c.Data;
```

But it would be very convenient to have access to this trough common parent A. For example with the below implementation I could to this:

```
class A  {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    //etc. common variables

    public virtual object DataAsObject {get;}
}

class B : A {
   public DataForB Data {get; set}
   public override object DataAsObject {get {return (object) Data; }}
}

class C : A {
   public DataForC Data {get; set}
   public override object DataAsObject {get {return (object) Data; }}
}
```

Now I can use the A to access the data object like this:

```
A b,c; //<- these have some real data

object objectB = b.DataAsObject;
object objectC = c.DataAsObject;
```

Annoying thing here is that I need to copy paste the same exact implementation to every class from B to X. It is of course in violation of the DRY principle.

Is there better way to do this. Or maybe some completely different pattern to achieve this.

**Update 1 : Solution with reflection**

One possible solution would be to use reflection like this:

```
A b,c; //<- these have some real data

object objectB = (object) b.GetType().GetProperty("Data").GetValue(b, null);
object objectC = (object) c.GetType().GetProperty("Data").GetValue(c, null);
```

Apparently reflection is pretty slow, but at least with my use case  (maximum of 10000 objects processed at once) the performance difference is next to none.

**Update 2: using generics**

Some answers suggest that this could be solved using generics, like this.

```
class A<T> {
    public T Data {get; set;}
}

class B:<StructForB> {...}
class C:<StructForC> {...}
```

This partially solves the problem. Only partially because when I am trying to access Data property trough A I would still need to define separate use cases.

In the example above (using annyoing DataAsObject property) I could do something like this:

```
List<A> list;
var dataObjects = list.Select(a => a.DataAsObject).ToList();
```

But as far as I understand this would not be possible when using generics, since there would need to be separate implementations for `A<StructForB>` and `A<StructForC>`.

Maybe I am missing something obvious here. Thank you very much for all of your advice.

Comment: Did you consider generics, like `class A<T>  { ... T Data { get; set; } }`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes I have considered this. But wouldn't I still need to define the actual struct (in the example DataForB and DataForC) when I am using the reference to the A. The syntax would be a bit nicer, but the problem would remain. Also since I am having this problem with entity framework data models I have some limitations with the use of generics.

Comment: Why are you using inheritance at all? And why are all of your properties mutable?

Comment: _"I need to copy paste the same exact implementation to every class from B to X. It is of course in violation of the DRY principle."_ - people need to learn that inheritance is not intended as a way to achieve DRY: inheritance should only be used to express an "is" relationship. _Yes_ having repetitive members is annoying, but that's how C# is designed (and we have T4 if you really want to go there...).

Comment: IMHO `abstract class A{ abstract object Data {get;} } class A<T>:A{...etc}`

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. It is very good point that inheritance is not meant to achieve DRY. Was just wondering, would there be a more DRY way to achieve what I am trying to do. This is of course very simple example, but in my actual use case there is a very strong conceptual link between the objects and the parent object.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to do this is to have a generic base class

```
class SomeBase<T>
{
    T Data { get; set; }
}
```

And to derive from that like so

```
class A : SomeBase<DataForA> {}
class B : SomeBase<DataForB> {}
```

This is DRY.

You mentioned you have limitations with generics. I’m not sure what you mean, but let’s suppose it’s true. You can at least do this, which is less type safe, but will “work”.

```
class SomeBase
{
    public object Data { get; set; }

    public T GetDataAs<T>() => (T)Data;
}
```

Still DRY, but definitely subject to runtime error.

If you can’t tolerate generics, runtime error or reflection your best bet is to generate code with a source generator or T4 templating.

Comment: @Gwydion - "generics" is absolutely the way to go.  Here's a good tutorial: https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/generics-csharp/  Based on what you're saying, you might not even need the subclasses.  Or the LINQ expression Kit suggested.  Use generics, [Keep it Simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment and reply. The problem with generics is that it only partially solves the problem. It makes defining the sub classes nice, but when using reference to SomeBase I still need to have separate implementations for each sub class. I will update the original question to clear this. Maybe I am understanding something wrong and I appreciate very much all of your insights.